# How to pass a list of files to add_custom_command in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am creating a zip file in CMake for every build I run. I have a list of every file I need to copy to the build directory and also add to the zip file. I have not figured out how can I pass the list to add_custom_command without manually re-listing all the files in the add_custom_command.

```
# Copy needed files to build directory
set (ADDITIONAL_FILES
    "${SOME_LIBRARY_DIR}/some_library.dll"
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/readme.txt"
)
foreach (file ${ADDITIONAL_FILES})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${file} NAME)
    configure_file(
        ${file}
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${file_name}" COPYONLY)
endforeach()

# Create release zip file
add_custom_command(OUTPUT
   "${PROJECT_NAME}_v${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}.zip"
   DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cfv"
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_v${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}.zip"
   --format=zip
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.exe"
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/some_library.dll"
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/readme.txt"
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "creating zip")
add_custom_target(run ALL
  DEPENDS "${PROJECT_NAME}_v${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}.zip"
)
```

How do I pass the list of files to add_custom_command?

Comment: Assuming you have a variable `FILES` containing list of `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/some_library.dll` and `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/readme.txt`, just use `${FILES}` for use this list. Not sure what is your problem.

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't seem to work. If I put ${ADDITIONAL_FILES} instead of the some_library.dll and readme.txt lines in add_custom_command I get no error but the zip file only contains the .exe file and nothing else. However copying the files using the same variable to the build folder seems to work fine.

Comment: Variable `ADDITIONAL_FILES` lists **original** files (under `SOME_LIBRARY_DIR` and `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` directories) , but you custom command wants **copied** files (under `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` directory). So you need to create another variable, which lists *copied* files.

Comment: True, but they are the same files anyway and exist at that point, shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Well, using `${ADDITIONAL_FILES}` (without quotes!) has the same effect as using `"${SOME_LIBRARY_DIR}/some_library.dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/readme.txt"`. That is, if your command correctly works with the second way, it should correctly work with the first. Exception could be in a case, when list elements themselves contain some unusual symbols like `;` (but containing a space shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: You seem to be correct, it does seem to work if I change the files in the list to come from PROJECT_BINARY_DIR. I am certain the files exist in both locations though so I don't still fully understand why it doesn't work with unmodified ADDITIONAL_FILES. Maybe something to do in which order things happen which is always unclear to me with CMake.

Comment: What do you mean by "work" or "not work"? Does zipping from files at their original location returns an error? Or you don't see that files after unpacking? As far as I understand from [zip documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip), an archive stores relative filenames, so on unpacking the files may be created out of the current directory.

Comment: Doesn't work: I get no error, the zip file just doesn't contain the files. Looking at the paths the ADDITIONAL_FILES paths are full correct paths, however the actual zipping step seems to convert them to relative paths for some reason. The paths are still correct though.